# Estimating how many fish in a pond

Tags: statistics

You have a pond that you want to know how many fish it contains. Say there are $N$ fish, then we want to esrimate $N$. To do so, you start catching fish and tagging them if they arent already tagged, then release them. This is an urn problem, sample with replacement, and the urn starts with red balls and when you sample a red ball you replace it with a green, and when you sample a green you just put it back in the urn.

There are two ways to approach this. Using a coupon collector type approach, let $T_i$ be the number of fish you have to catch until you get one that hasnt been tagged, and you then use your $i^{th}$ tag. Then each $T_i$ has a geometric distribution and
$E(T_1+\cdots+T_i)=N(\frac{1}{N}+\cdots+\frac{1}{N-i+1})$

So, for example, if we use the third tag on the tenth fish we catch, then our estimate for $N$ would need to satisfy

$10\approx N(\frac{1}{N}+\frac{1}{N-1}+\frac{1}{N-2})$

Which is impossible! The right hand sum is typically around 3.something for values of $N$, try plugging in a few values if you need.

The second approach is to let $p(i,t)$ be probability that after catching $t$ fish we have used $i$ tags. Then using a conditioning argument we get
$p(i,t)=\frac{t}{N}p(i-1,t)+\frac{N-t+1}{N}p(i-1,t-1)$
Along with some trivial initial conditions, and so we can pick the value of $N$ that maximizes the expression for $p(3,10)$. This gives a reasonable result.

So my question is, why is the first, relatively easy, approach seemingly wrong?

Comment: Maybe useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_and_recapture and/or https://www.nps.gov/piro/learn/education/howmanyfish.htm and/or section 6 here http://oak.snr.missouri.edu/nr3110/

Comment: Neither of the cases you mentioned fit the assumptions well. The question remains, why is the estimator obtained from the generic coupon collecting problem so bad?

Comment: I am not so sure about your statement "if we use the third tag on the tenth fish we catch". For this fascinating problem (ICCP - Inverse Coupon Collector’s Problem) here there are another materials: https://sites.google.com/site/rbeeman976/home/collector and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/87494/estimating-n-in-coupon-collectors-problem

Comment: That is perfect, thanks a lot!